# US freight railroad networks, stations, yards and junctions

Tags: data-request, transportation, network-structure

I am looking for a dataset containing US freight railroad networks, stations,  yards and junctions for class I railroads for all US states.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try Openstreetmap and its data dumps.  Should be pretty complete for railroads.

Answer (score 4):

The US Department of Transportation has a dataset called the [National Transportation Atlas Database](https://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index.html).

https://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index.html

The [Liner Notes](https://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2015/liner) describe the datasets that are included.

At that link go to NTAD 2015 (online),  Polyline, Railway Network

Also under the Points category, these datasets are related to the railroad:

- Amtrak Stations
- Intermodal Terminal Facilities
- Railroad Grade Crossings

OpenStreetMap data may be more accurate in some spots, in other spots it won't have any coverage or the attributes will be incomplete.

I'm also looking for US Railroad data at a better scale than this, but so far this is the best I've found.

Comment: A follow up question, is it possible to calculate miles of tracks owned by railroad company in a given geographical unit (i.e. county) from the spatial network of rail lines in National Transportation Atlas Database?

Comment: Yes, the attribute table has fields for track owner, mileage and county.

Answer (score 1):

The best data on stations and junctions that I've found so far is Railinc's website Steelroads: https://www.steelroads.com/steelroads/servlet/GenericServlet?CONTROLLER=IrfMenuController&ACTION=MENU_INITIALIZE&LANGUAGE=en

It's like a free extract from Railinc's Centralized Station Master File (which is usually around $2000). It has station's code, location name, state, standard point location code and type of station (operating or revenue), if it is a junction, and if so, name of the junction.

You can not download the file, so I had to spend some time scraping the website.

Also a major drawback is that it does not contain expired stations, only the ones that are operating at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

[US DOT Open Data Portal Search for Keyword "Rail"](http://osav-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets?keyword=Rail) has datasets, including:
Railroad Crossings, Transit Network, Railroad Lines, Transit Stations, Intermodal Transit Facilities (IPCD), Amtrak Routes, Amtrak Stations.